# CONDA 4.8: conda activate --stack doesn't work

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to stack virtual environments in conda so that i can simply access the modules from other environments. To achieve this, i researched and found out `conda activate --stack env_name` which is i think not working.

Here are my tests:

```
(base) C:\Users\ggwp>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3
cpy382-django-practice-env     C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-django-practice-env
cpy382-env               C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env


(base) C:\Users\ggwp>echo %conda_shlvl%
1



(base) C:\Users\ggwp>conda activate cpy382-env

(cpy382-env) C:\Users\ggwp>echo %path%
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\Library\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\Scripts;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\bin;C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\condabin;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts;
C:\Users\ggwp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;
C:\Users\ggwp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.

(cpy382-env) C:\Users\ggwp>pip show gmaps
Name: gmaps
Version: 0.9.0
Summary: Google maps plugin for Jupyter notebooks
Home-page: https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps
Author: Pascal Bugnion
Author-email: pascal@bugnion.org
License: UNKNOWN
Location: c:\users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\lib\site-packages
Requires: ipython, geojson, six, traitlets, ipywidgets
Required-by:


(cpy382-env) C:\Users\ggwp>conda activate --stack cpy382-django-practice-env

(cpy382-django-practice-env) C:\Users\ggwp>echo %path%
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-django-practice-env;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-django-practice-env\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-django-practice-env\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-django-practice-env\Library\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-django-practice-env\Scripts;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-django-practice-env\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\Library\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\Scripts;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\envs\cpy382-env\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\anaconda3\condabin;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin;
C:\Users\ggwp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts;
C:\Users\ggwp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;
C:\Users\ggwp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.


(cpy382-django-practice-env) C:\Users\ggwp>echo %conda_shlvl%
3

(cpy382-django-practice-env) C:\Users\ggwp>pip show gmaps
WARNING: Package(s) not found: gmaps
```

**So that's my problem, even in the path the stack works. But still i can't use gmaps from** `cpy382-env`. I'm expecting that, i should be able to use gmaps module after using `--stack` in `cpy382-django-practice-env`. I don't know what's wrong, please help. Thanks :)

Comment: Unlike executables, python modules are not located via the `path` variable, so `--stack` cannot help you here. It is possible to leak packages from one environment into others via the `PYTHONPATH` variable, but this rarely is a good idea as it defeats the purpose of using isolated environments.

Comment: _I want to stack virtual environments in conda so that i can simply access the modules from other environments._ Why? What benefits does that offer?

Comment: i don't need to reinstall same modules again and again when i need them in other environment?

Comment: In support of @EnisDelMar, I want to do a similar thing. If you are familiar with Docker, it's a similar notion: so you don't have to start from scratch every time i.e. re-download every package when you've got a stable state environment in one place and you just want to add a bit too it.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same problem, but apparently we misunderstood the use of conda stack: is *not* meant to combine the environments' python packages.

After some research and finally the (official) documentation, I understood the *stacking* is *not* about Python modules but rather command-line tools. It is meant to combine the elements of `PATH` from the previous (eg, `base`) with the "new" environment.

From [the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html?highlight=stack#nested-activation):

> Sometimes you may want to leave the current environment PATH entries in place so that you can continue to easily access command-line programs from the first environment. This is most commonly encountered when common command-line utilities are installed in the base environment. To retain the current environment in the PATH, you can activate the new environment using:
>
> ```
> conda activate --stack myenv
> ```